# 1mpl3m3nt vector stack & output a stored&counted item

Tags: objective-c-runtime

Here's my code:

I currently have everything the user enters dumped into the stack and sorted, but I don't how/where to go from here. I tried solving it with a count variable, but my solution isn't proper (it should output "2 dog" only once if the user enters dog twice). If anybody can help or knows a way to solve this, please give an example.

Comment: Consider just using a [`std::map<std::string, unsigned int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). And fyi, your existing input loop would include a count of 1 for your `endString` entry, which you probably won't want anyway.

Comment: using a map is the way to go but are you looking at an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use map. But if you are searching for another answer, use a search over all elements.
after you read all elements from input, start looping over vector. get first element, store its value and remove it then check other size-1 elements to see if they are equal to this one. if yes, add counter and remove the item from vector. 
Notice that size has decreased. now again do the same till size becomes 0.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do this. The easiest is a simple use of [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, unsigned int> mymap;
    std::string s;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, s) && !s.empty() && s != "END")
        ++mymap[s];

    for (auto const& pr : mymap)
        std::cout << pr.second << ':' << pr.first << '\n';
}
```

**How it works**

- Each line is read, and if successful (not eof, not empty, and not equivalent to "END") is used for updating an entry in the map.
- Per the [documentation for `std::map::operator []`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), if the requisite key is not already present in the map, it is added, and mapped-to value is *value-initialized*. For `unsigned int` that means the initial value is `0`.
- From there, the increment is applied to the returned `unsigned int` reference, which for a new element, results in the value `1`, for existing elements, it simply increments the prior value.
- This continues until the loop terminates.

Upon termination of the loop the results are reported in lexicographical order, preceded by their count.

**Input**

```
one
two
three
four
three
one
one
one
two
END
```

**Output**

```
1:four
4:one
2:three
2:two
```

---

If you wanted to sort the output based on count, more work would need to be done, but it isn't difficult. A set of pairs from the map, inverted so the count is first, the string second, makes short work of that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, unsigned int> mymap;
    std::string s;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, s) && !s.empty() && s != "END")
        ++mymap[s];

    std::set<std::pair<unsigned int, std::string>> ms;
    for (auto const& pr : mymap)
        ms.insert(std::make_pair(pr.second, pr.first));

    for (auto const& pr : ms)
        std::cout << pr.first << ':' << pr.second << '\n';
}
```

An example run appears below:

**Input**

```
one
two
three
four
three
one
one
one
two
END
```

**Output**

```
1:four
2:three
2:two
4:one
```

Comment: @danZster You need a compiler and standard library implementation compliant with C++11 or later to build this (because of the range-`for` usage). If you're using g++ or clang the appropriate switch is `-std=c++11`. I don't know the switches for Visual C++, so if that's what you're using you'll have to investigate it. Sorry, if that is the case. You could always use iterators rather than ranged-for and it should be compliant back to C++98.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::map as mentioned in comment:

```
std::map<std::string, unsigned int> countMap;

while(enter!=endString){
    getline(cin,enter);
    countMap[enter]++;   // Operator `[]` enters a new key if not present and 
    // default initializes the value. 
    //, else fetches and increases the corresponding value
}

// coutMap[str] gives the number of times `str` entered.
```